# How to display Hindi or Gujarati Font using Bluetooth Printer?

Tags: android, printing, android-bluetooth

I am using [Android-Bluetooth-Printer](https://github.com/pradeepksingh/Android-Bluetooth-Printer).it works fine if i type English text in `edittext`,but the issue is if i select hindi language from soft keyboard,and then i enter some hindi text and try to print,but it display nothing in paper.

```
public class BlueToothPrinterApp extends Activity       
{       

    EditText message;
    Button printbtn;

    byte FONT_TYPE;
    private static BluetoothSocket btsocket;
    private static OutputStream btoutputstream;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        printbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.printButton);

        printbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                connect();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void connect() {
        if(btsocket == null){
            Intent BTIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BTDeviceList.class);
            this.startActivityForResult(BTIntent, BTDeviceList.REQUEST_CONNECT_BT);
        }
        else{

            OutputStream opstream = null;
            try {
                opstream = btsocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            btoutputstream = opstream;
            print_bt();

        }

    }


    private void print_bt() {
        try {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            btoutputstream = btsocket.getOutputStream();

            byte[] printformat = { 0x1B, 0x21, FONT_TYPE };
            btoutputstream.write(printformat);
            String msg = message.getText().toString();
            btoutputstream.write(msg.getBytes());
            btoutputstream.write(0x0D);
            btoutputstream.write(0x0D);
            btoutputstream.write(0x0D);
            btoutputstream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if(btsocket!= null){
                btoutputstream.close();
                btsocket.close();
                btsocket = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            btsocket = BTDeviceList.getSocket();
            if(btsocket != null){
                print_bt();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: have you achieved this.I am also need in same thing.

Comment: @Murali yes,,just try with given answer

Comment: I tried with image printing.But printer fall into stack overflow.Can post your working code if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printers have predefined character sets built in. These character sets are known as [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page).

Your Bluetooth printer, like most POS printers doesn't seem to support Unicode.

To solve this you could try converting your output to an image and send it to the printer as bytes using an emulation the printer understands.(PCL, ESC/POS, ZPL etc.)